# Java try-catch infinite loop when input a character

Tags: java

I want to make a try-catch exception that only accept 1-5 or 9 input. So I wrote the following code.

```
    try {
            step1 = scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error! Input accept integers only. Input 1-5 or 9");
            System.out.println("");
            continue;
        }
```

The result is that if I input an invalid number, it gave me an error (That's true). But when I input a character, it gave me an infinite loop. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: use `scanner.nextLine()` in your exception to catch the carriage return.

Comment: Printing the stack trace of the exception might give you a clue as to the problem.

Comment: I see no loop. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i don´t know how your loop looks i´ll just go with an endless loop in my answer. In the normal case, the `nextInt` method wont catch the carriage return, and if you input something that is not a number you need to call `nextLine` to catch this. If you don´t do this you might run into an infinity loop if you are using any kind of loop that just asks for `nextInt`. This could solve the problem:

```
while(true) {
    int step1;
    try {
        step1 = s.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Input accept integers only. Input 1-5 or 9");
        System.out.println("");
    } finally { // Use a finally block to catch the carriage return, no matter if the int that got input was valid or not.
        s.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm new to Java and doesn't realize that 'nextInt' method won't catch the carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must parse input before decision making.
Sorry for my bad English, I'm not a native speaker also.

Answer (score 0):

try this, which make all the tests

```
int step1;

while (true)
{
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 try {
     step1 = scanner.nextInt();

     if (((step1>=1) && (step1<=5)) || (step1==9))
            // BINGO
            break;       
 }
 catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    }

 System.out.println("Error! Input accept integers only. Input 1-5 or 9");
 System.out.println("");
 // it loops ther
}   

System.out.println("You are done ! "+step1);
```